# Loop animation until button is pressed, but let animation finish

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, animate-cc

Well I know what I must do, just don't know how.

I know I have to (after make all my animations and whatnot) declare all variables on frame 1(in a seperate time-line), like a=0;b=0...

Then do a gotoandplay at the end of the loop to the begging, with a condition (in frame 120, if a=0 gotoandplay (100) otherwise gotoandplay(15)

And then have a button to change the value of a, so that when the loop meets the conditional it goes to whatever frame I want.

Any pointers?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understood the issue, but, you can have another variable like `buttonClicked:Boolean` which you set to true once user clicks the button, and add it to your loop condition as well so that it keeps looping only if `buttonClicked == false`

Comment: So, instead of a, b, c, d integer variables I would have buttoncli ked1, buttonclicked2, etc in the first frame, setting them as false, then have everything the same, and only change the conditional to keep looping if button is still not clicked, once it's clicked it will finish the loop, check the conditional and do another thing right?

I might edit the post later to add reference code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've taken both of yours suggestions, and did this

1 animation, with a circle going left and right and a button going from frame 1-20 and text saying "Done" one layer 21

3 layers : 
Actions
Button
Layer 1 (animation layer)

After that i set on Action frame 1, the code

```
var loop:Boolean =true
```

And on frame 20

```
if (loop==true){
        gotoAndPlay(2);
}else {
gotoAndStop(21)
}
```

Then on the button, did

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked, false, 0, true);
function buttonClicked(e:Event):void {
    loop=false
    }
```

And it worked. the loop finishes and only then it goes to the 21st frame, and stops there.

Am i missing something? or is this a good solution? (also, might use this for a menu, with case instead of if's and integer values to jump to which chapter i want)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your button has an instance name of `btn` and you looping animation has an instance name of `mc_loop`.

You can do something like this:

```
//listen for the mouse click on your button
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked, false, 0, true);

//run this function on the click
function buttonClicked(e:Event):void {
    //add a script to the last frame that calls this inline function
    //the addFrameScript method wants a 0 based frame number, so the first frame would be 0,  the last frame would the total frame count less 1
    mc_loop.addFrameScript(mc_loop.totalFrames-1, function(){
        mc_loop.stop(); //stop the clip so it doesn't loop anymore
        mc_loop.addFrameScript(mc_loop.totalFrames-1, null); //remove the frame script so it doesn't run again should mc_loop reach the last frame again
    });
}
```

With this code, assuming `mc_loop` is already playing/looping, clicking the `btn` will stop it once it reaches its last frame.

Comment: So i've taken both of yours suggestions, and did this

1 animation, with a circle going left and right and a button.

3 layers : Actions